# Looking to find text columnar position verification tool. Does one exist?

Tags: validation, input

I am working on creating text based data feed files that have fixed column widths. Example: Position 1-5 is record layout ID, position 6-35 is part number, position 36-70 is description, etc.

I wish there were a tool I could provide these data input widths, then paste in the raw text to visually see where it lines up. Conceptually, this would seem to be a pretty simple tool.

Do you know of any solutions or creative ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr

Layout Id would be str.substr(1, 5)
Part number would be str.substr(6, 35)
etc.